# Database Test com Spring Boot

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

Pessoal estou com um erro, quando executo minha aplicação com o profile test, o Spring Boot não cria o database igual no profile local.
Alguma sugestão?

Segue o meu arquivo application-local.properties:

```
# Hibernate
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE

spring.datasource.username=rw_itau
spring.datasource.password=rw_itau
spring.datasource.url=jdbc\:postgresql\://localhost/rw_itau
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

E o arquivo application-test.properties:

```
# Hibernate
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE

spring.datasource.username=rw_itau
spring.datasource.password=rw_itau
spring.datasource.url=jdbc\:postgresql\://localhost/rw_itau_teste
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

Além disso tenho varias classes como a classe inicial do SpringBoot:

```
package br.com.zup.rw.itau;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

@SpringBootApplication
@Controller
public class Boot
{

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      SpringApplication.run(Boot.class, args);
   }

}
```

Estou usando Maven e o Docker com o Banco Postgres o erro gerado é este:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: database "rw_itau_teste"
>   does not exist

Eu executo o projeto com este argumento:

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=test
```

Porém quando executo com o argumento local, o banco é criado normalmente.

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=local
```

Quando executo o segundo profile da erro ao conectar no banco.

Comment: Você poderia atualizar sua questão com um teste de exemplo (com an anotações de configuração e tudo mais que for necessário), sua estrutura de pastas e as partes relevantes do maven / gradle / sistema de build?

Comment: Veja se melhorou? Estou usando o Maven, mas nao acredito que tenha algo de muito importante além do springboot, para postar

Comment: Renato, eu postaria as configurações de teste com `@TestPropertySource`, `@ActiveProfiles`, etc e um teste. Pode estar faltando alguma anotação, algum arquivo pode estar na pasta errada, etc.

Comment: Opa meus arquivos de properties estão todos na pasta resources src/main/resources. Estou usando a annotation @ActiveProfiles("test") em minha classe teste, somente para o projeto entender que profile usar. Além dessa tenho essas configurações no meu teste: RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
SpringBootTest
AutoConfigureMockMvc
AutoConfigureRestDocs(outputDir = "target/snippets")

Comment: Tente mover o arquivo `application-test.properties` para `src/test/resources`. Se não der certo por favor atualize a pergunta com um  [MVCE](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly pelo q entendi ate agora o sistema esta abrindo o application-test.properties, corretamente ele somente nao consegue criar o banco, o estranho é que em application-local.properties o banco foi criado normalmente.

Comment: Achei o problema era bem idiota na vdd, estou criando um único database no Docker, so preciso aprender a criar multiplus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa Tarde

```
  spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

Essa propriedade não cria o database(banco), somente as tabelas do database(banco). Crie manualmente no Postgres, e você verá que irar rodar e criar as tabelas.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html

Solução: você pode criar no metodo main uma  Conexão JDBC executando PreparedStatemente.executeQuery("create database rw_itau_teste").

Utilizar o flywayDb conforme no link acima, usando migration;

Espero ter ajudado.